# TestNG marking test run as failed after test case retry has passed

Tags: java, testng

I have implemented a RetryAnalyzer simple retry logic on failed tests with TestNG. To ensure failed/skipped retries are removed from the final results, I have also implemented a RetryListener extending from TestListenerAdapter. When the test suite executes and a test case fails, it retries a max number of times until passes. For each failed retry, I marked the test result with a "RETRIED" attribute. I have checked at the end of the execution the failed/skipped retries (which are marked) are removed from the results. But TestNG reports the test suite as failed, even though the last retry passes. This is messing up my report metrics because test suites which are passing (after retrying) are getting reported as failed.

This is the implementation I have:

**RetryAnalyzer.java**

```java
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 0;
    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 2;
    static final String RETRIED_ATTRIBUTE = "Retried";

    @Override
    public boolean retry(final ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount < MAX_RETRIES) {
            retryCount++;
            result.setAttribute(RETRIED_ATTRIBUTE, true);
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Retrying test case %s of %s times", retryCount, MAX_RETRIES));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**RetryListener.java**

```java
public class RetryListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onFinish(final ITestContext testContext) {

        super.onFinish(testContext);
        final IResultMap skippedTests = testContext.getSkippedTests();
        final IResultMap failedTests = testContext.getFailedTests();

        skippedTests.getAllResults()
                    .removeIf(testResult -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(testResult.getAttribute(RETRIED_ATTRIBUTE)));

        failedTests.getAllResults()
                   .removeIf(testResult -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(testResult.getAttribute(RETRIED_ATTRIBUTE)));
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.